# How can I see what content an XMLHttp request returned to the page?

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox

I use Firefox, and there is a tool called Developer -> Web Console. It shows more information about GET/POST requests, which page we connected with XMLHttp, request headers and information like this. I'm sure there is a similar feature on Chrome too.

There is an AJAX call on a page and I have to see what it returns to the website. It is just a GET request and returns JSON. When I manually request that page (e.g ajax/view/my_purchases.php) it just shows a blank page, but when the website requests it with AJAX, I can see what content it returned in HTML.

Basically, What kind of tools I can use to see it? 
It can be a standalone application, Chrome or a Firefox extension. I'm okay with any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is the most used option. Net panel has "XHR" tab that you can use, and chrome tools were actually based on that.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Now I can see everything related to the ajax call. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

on chrome you have the "network" tab, all requests and responses are there, 
also you can put a breakpoint in the "success" function and watch the response.
p.s
chrome has this console without any extentions

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebug on Firefox -> Console Tab (maybe aktivate "show XMLHttpRequests")

Edit: nicer than on Chrome you can open the request directly in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'Net' tab, you can view every single external request that the page is calling when it loads. Your AJAX request will be in here. One thing to look out for is any GET or POST data being sent to the external script.

Many scripts will only provide access to its main algorithm or data logic if it expects certain parameters. A very basic one might be:

```
<?php

   if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      die;
   }

   // Rest of functionality...
```

This makes it harder for people to gain access to sensitive data. If your AJAX call is sending POST data, you probably won't gain access. And if you do, you'll be committing [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).